# Firefox podcast downloads won't complete

Tags: firefox, download

I've been having a strange problem when downloading files with Firefox (3.5.3).

When I start downloading the podcast, the download will run for a few (5-10) seconds, and then no more data will download.  The amount downloaded will no longer increment, yet the download rate indicator will still say nKb/sec, as though it is still downloading.  If I stop the download, the file isn't completely done and its corrupt.  If I pause the download, and start it again, it appears to resume just fine (the amount downloaded will increment again, and the rate indicator will change), but often it will get stuck again after around 5-10 seconds.  After maybe 2-3 iterations of pause/restart, the file will usually then continue without any problems and complete downloading.  If I don't pause/restart, the download never completes (I let it sit over the weekend once and it never completed).

While the pause/restart trick works (I mean, I eventually get my file downloaded), I have to babysit the download first, which isn't fun.

I've noticed this usually happens with podcasts and other mp3 files most often, usually around 20-30MB.  It's happened maybe once or twice with larger zipfiles.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your network path has some losses and the connection is timing out.
Consider using some download plugin like [**DownThemAll**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) or
try '`wget`' from a terminal (which will retry the connection).

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a lot of quirks in Firefox's download manager over the years. My solution was to use a plugin like [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201).